# jQuery Filter on select

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a jQuery filter  to filter some divs.

The HTML filter is
When a option is selected the class="active" is added to that line ( ex: )

```
<div class="panel style1 arrow-right">
    <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href=
    "#board-type-filter">Board Type</a></h4>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="board-type-filter">
        <div class="panel-content">
            <ul class="check-square filters-option">
                <li data-board-id="board-all">
                    <a href="#">Toate<small class="total"></small></a>
                </li>
                <li data-board-id="RO">
                    <a href="#">Room Only<small class="total-ro"></small></a>
                </li>
                <li data-board-id="BB">
                    <a href="#">Bed and Breakfast<small class=
                    "total-bb"></small></a>
                </li>
                <li data-board-id="CB">
                    <a href="#">Continental Breakfast<small class=
                    "total-cb"></small></a>
                </li>
                <li data-board-id="HB">
                    <a href="#">Half Board<small class="total-hb"></small></a>
                </li>
                <li data-board-id="FB">
                    <a href="#">Full Board<small class="total-fb"></small></a>
                </li>
                <li data-board-id="AI">
                    <a href="#">All Inclusive<small class=
                    "total-ai"></small></a>
                </li>
                <li data-board-id="UI">
                    <a href="#">Ultra All İnclusive<small class=
                    "total-ui"></small></a>
                </li>
                <li data-board-id="SC">
                    <a href="#">Self Catering<small class=
                    "total-sc"></small></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The HTML content to be filtered is :

```
<div data-board="Half Board">Half Board</div>
<div data-board="Full Board">Full Board</div>
<div data-board="All Inclusive">All Inclusive</div>
....
```

Before this i had a filter with checkboxes, but it was not styled up as the above .
Old jQuery filter is:

```
var grabVal = "";
      $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e){
      $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
      grabVal = $(this).val();
              if(!$(this).is(":checked")){
      $("div[data-board='"+grabVal+"']").hide();
              }else{
      $("div[data-board='"+grabVal+"']").show();
              }
          });

              if(!$("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")){
      $("div").show();   
          }
```

Witch is better a scipt to action on click or a scipt with data url action (page load and get filter information from the url) ?

Any advice will be much appreciate. Please let me know if you need any more information.
Also please forgive my n00bie. :)

Comment: what do you mean by **needs filtered**?

Comment: i have correct, the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right you have to create a connection between the `<li>...</li>` element you click and the container (or containers) of the information connected to the selected values.

I hypothesized a solution based on a custom class. For example,

```
<li data-board-id="HB"> <a href="#">Half Board<small class="total-hb"></small></a>
```

clicking on this will display the content of the following container and hide the content of the other containers:

```
<div class="detail HB-detail">Details for Half Board</div>
```

The logic is handled as follows:

```
$("#board-type-filter LI").on("click", function () {
    $(".detail").hide(500);
    $("." + $(this).attr("data-board-id") + "-detail").show(500)
});
```

Full example here (edited to support the `all` option): http://jsfiddle.net/8vwbpLtv/3/

Comment: and when i click "All", how can i get them all show up? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: you can handle the specific id differently from all others and display all elements belonging to the "detail" class". I updated the answer to include this case.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that will help you a bit : http://jsfiddle.net/txc59qzd/1/
Not really optimized but can help you to understand...

```
$('.filter').click(function () {
    var filter = $(this).data('filter');

    if (filter == 'all') {
        $('.mix').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('.mix').addClass('hide');
        $('.mix' + filter).removeClass('hide');
    }

    $('.filter').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

});
```